# Margin does not work on android 2.3.5 device

Tags: android, xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/phone_number_" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/numberText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/message_" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/messageText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/troll_sequence_" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sqence"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="@string/_15" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/trollBtn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/start_trolling" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/stop_trolling" />
```

this is my xml layout code and i set for linear layout the default margin from @dimen and it is 16dp. but when i run on HTC Wildfire S that run android 2.3.5 it's not working and my object on screen have no margine from left and top.anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this margin for views not for parent layout like

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/message_" 
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I too got the same problem.I tried padding instead of margin and it worked.

Comment: thanks that work but why it's not working? because on android 4 and higher working well

Comment: padding moves the items which are inside(within the boundary)  whereas margin moves outside(out of boundary).